# What is the victory rally?

Tags: the-hunger-games

In *Catching Fire* (*The Hunger Games*), Katniss mentions that there is a victory rally in the square on the last day of the Harvest Festival during her Victory Tour. What is a victory rally?

Comment: Maybe, and I'm just blue-skying here, a "victory rally" is a _rally_ on the _Victory_ tour.

Comment: [Rally, n.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rally#Noun): "a public gathering or mass meeting... to inspire enthusiasm for a cause".

Comment: You might be interested in our sister site [ell.se]. Please take their tour and read up in their help centre *before* posting, as you should on any site on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my re-reading of Catching Fire, the victory rally appears to happen in every district, to celebrate the victor(s) survival in the arena.

> District 11. Our first stop. I'd rather start in any other district since this was Rue's home. But that's not how the **Victory Tour** works. Usually, it kicks off in 12 and then goes in descending district order to 1, followed by the capital. Victor's district is skipped and saved for the very last. Since 12 puts on the least fabulous celebration —  usually just a  dinner for the tributes and a **victory rally** in the square, where nobody looks like they're having any fun — it's probably best to get us out of the way as soon as possible. This year, for the first time since Haymitch won, the final stop on the tour will be 12, and the Capitol will spring for the festivities [ . . . ]
> The agenda for District 12 includes a dinner at Mayor Undersee's house tonight **and a  victory rally in the square** during the  Harvest Festival tomorrow. **We always celebrate the Harvest Festival on the final day of the Victory Tour**, but usually, it means a meal at home or with a few friends if you can afford it. This year it will be a public affair, and since the Capitol will be throwing it, everyone in the whole district will have full bellies

All text in the quotes relevant to the point is bolded :)

Answer (score -2):

Just a rally in honor of her victory.

Comment: If OP doesn't know what a rally is, telling them that **a rally is a rally** isn't going to be much help to them

Comment: Yes, please provide more context